# Declartive Transaction in spring is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, transactions

I am using spring declarative Transaction features. Something like this

XML file for `spring configuration`..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
            <property name="username" value="root" />
            <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Add this tag to enable annotations transactions -->

    <tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Dao Layer code

package com.dao;

```
@Repository("commonDao")
public class CommonDaoImpl implements CommonDao {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CommonDaoImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(){
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public Object makePayment(Object e) {
            String sql = "insert into payment (id, name, amount) values('abc', 100)";
            try{
                return jdbcTemplate.update(sql);    
            }catch(DataAccessException ex){
                throw ex;
            }
    }

    @Override
    public Object signUp(Object e) {

            String sql = "insert into login (userid, password) values('naveen', 'password')";
            return jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
    }

}
```

`Service Layer code`

```
@Service
public class CommonServiceImpl implements CommonService {

    @Autowired
    private CommonDao commonDao;

//  @Transactional I tried both of them one by one but not worked
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    @Override
    public boolean makePayment() {
        try{
            commonDao.signUp(new Object());
            commonDao.makePayment(new Object());    
        } catch(DataAccessException ex){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

but when i send call `makePayment()` method via controller then it save the record into login table but failed when it move to insert into payment table because i write query so that it can through an exception. I do not understand why transaction is not working. because @Transactional annotation is on makePayment method so not operation should happen in db.

Please tell what's wrong in this code.

Comment: what you want do exactly

Comment: I want to follow the ACID property, means either both record should be inserted or none of them.

Comment: So you are saying that the a row gets added in the login table even when the commonDao.makePayment() throws exception?

Comment: yes, but it should not happend.

Comment: i am still struggling. can some one tell me why it is  happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SQL` query in in `makePayment` method is :

```
insert into payment (id, name, amount) values('abc', 100)
```

You are asking the query to insert `id`, `name` and `amount` in the database table, but providing only 2 values i.e. `abc` and `100`.

If `id` column in the table is `autoincrement` id then you don't need to mention it in the `SQL` query. Your `SQL` query in the `makePayment` method should be like this:

```
insert into payment (name, amount) values('abc', 100)
```

Comment: I am doing it intentionally. so that transaction get failed due to this error and no record should insert into tables. But record is inserted into login table. It should not happed if transaction is working.